# Anaconda in C Drive issue

Tags: anaconda, conda

I would like to install pytorch on my computer. However, Anaconda takes up 7GB in my C Drive which occupies too much space. My Python IDLE is currently in C Drive. What can I do to resolve this issue? I tried putting Anaconda in D Drive but the command prompt does not seem to work.

Should I reinstall all my python downloads (Atom, IDLE) in D Drive?

My D Drive has PLENTY OF SPACE

Answer (score -1):

> Anaconda takes up 7GB in my C Drive which occupies too much space

Why not use `miniconda` or something similar instead? It only comes with a minimal installation of packages.

You can always create an environment in a location of your choice.

```
conda create --prefix D:\condaEnvs\torchEnv pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

and then activate it with

```
conda activate D:\condaEnvs\torchEnv
```

Comment: I would like to use anaconda

Comment: Is it possible to link anaconda D Drive to my python in C Drive?

Comment: I don't know what you mean exactly by that? You can keep your installation location and the base env on your C drive and then create envs for specific projects on your D drive.